# Can Mercurial store, but not version, files?

Tags: web, version-control, mercurial

I'm working on a static website that I'd like to version using Mercurial.

However, I want to handle **images** and **libraries** (e.g. jQuery, Bootstrap, etc.) specially.

Specifically, I want Mercurial to store these files, but not track their changes.

**For example:** If I push an update to an image file, the updated image should simply clobber the version on the server. I don't want Mercurial to bother diffing or storing deltas. So as far as the version control system is concerned, the file should always remain at version 1. Also, if I delete an image file from source control it should be gone forever.

Is there a way to do this? Is this a good approach for handling images and libraries?

Comment: Why?  What problem are you trying to solve by attempting this?  `"Is this a good approach for handling images and libraries?"` - I'd say that it isn't, because the versioning is for the entire codebase and not just individual files.  If only some files are tracked, then you're overwriting history in the versioning.

Comment: In web design, images are subject to frequent changes which are not important to track. I feel tracking such changes will cause the repo to grow large with a change history we don't care much about. So I'd like to keep things simple and track the latest versions only. Libraries on the other hand aren't subject to change, but I thought it would be convenient to track them using the same method.

Comment: Consider a situation where Version 1 of the application use Version 1 of a given file.  By the time you get to Version 10 of the application, somewhere along the way Version 2 of the file came along.  Now you can no longer reliably recreate any previous version of the application.  For tests, production hot fixes, etc.  All previous versions have been altered and no longer match what they originally were.  If some resources truly shouldn't be versioned, then they shouldn't be in the source in the first place.  Put them elsewhere, such as a CDN host.

Comment: I would buy that argument if this indeed was an "application." But it's simply a static website with no server-side component. Using a CDN sounds like a good idea though, but somewhat inconvenient if I do not have a reliable internet connection while I'm working.

Comment: Honestly, it really sounds like you're inventing a problem that doesn't actually exist.  Is there really so much data that disk space is becoming constrained?  That server processing time is constrained during check-in?  If so then that's a prime candidate for something like a CDN, which is designed to handle vast amounts of data like that.  (It can be an internally-hosted one, to take care of the reliable internet connection problem.)  But if none of these problems actually exist... then no problem actually exists.

Answer (score 3):

This is not how modern version control systems work (Mercurial, Git, Subversion, whatever). In modern VCSs, commits are *atomic*, meaning that all changes represented by a commit make up an indivisible whole. You cannot go back and later throw out part of the commit (well, to some extent you can in Mercurial with `hg convert` and in Git with `git filter-branch`, but those are expensive and potentially dangerous operations, because they have to reprocess the entire repository).

There are possibly ways to approximate what your requirements appear to be (at least as far as minimizing disk usage on the server goes). The largefiles extension (distributed with Mercurial) represents large files (such as images) by a cryptographic fingerprint instead and keeps them in a cache, to be downloaded only on demand (and if you really know what you are doing, you can even delete older versions, though that is not necessarily safe or supported, and can break your repository in subtle ways). The [remotefilelog extension](https://bitbucket.org/facebook/remotefilelog) that Facebook uses has a more sophisticated caching scheme, but requires non-trivial setup effort and a reasonably fast connection between client and server.

Answer (score 2):

You can [exclude files](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html) from Mercurial's tracking. This would have the desired effect but if you're using Mercurial for deployment (e.g. pulling changes down to the live server) the images/libraries would not get included.

However, I see no reason why you'd want to avoid the versioning for images/libraries. I can't imagine a use case where including images/libraries would cause enough trouble to require workarounds. Unless you have a very good reason, include the images/libraries in Mercurial and be done with it.

Comment: Excluding files isn't convenient. As you mentioned, if I attempt to deploy the project or setup another build environment, the images and libraries will not be populated. The reason I don't want to version images is because it seems wasteful to diff and store deltas several times simply because I change a color from blue, then to red, then back to blue again.  Simply put, tracking these changes isn't useful and takes up space for no clear benefit.

Comment: @AlfaZulu There is no reason to commit changes (and thus create deltas) until you're satisfied unless you're developing by making changes locally, committing, and then pushing to a server. If this is the case, you should be developing locally and then pushing when you want to share your changes with other people.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do this?

Yes. you can

- add these assets in v.1 into Mercurial
- hgignore all "single version" files immediately after it

As result, all later changes will be invisible (TBT!!!)

> Is this a good approach for handling images and libraries?

No, it's **THE VERY BAD IDEA (tm)** and fooling history